# Email value not showing using POST method

Tags: php, email

I have this form in which there is only one field i.e. "Email id", so what I have to do is that when I entered the email id the email id must be split into two parts like `user name` and `domain name` and must be displayed in next form.
So my problem is that my 2nd form doesn't display the result, however when I used `$_SESSION` method in place of `$_POST`(to take value of email field) it takes the value and also split it but takes only one value as I want to take multiple email ids.
For better understanding please check my code.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="screen3_controller.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email_text">Email:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control"  name="email_text" id="email_text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Email Id</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['all_post']) && !empty($_SESSION['all_post']))
                    {
                       foreach($_SESSION['all_post'] as $key=>$value)
                       {
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $value['email_text']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User Name</th>
                        <th>Domain Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $str = $_POST['email_text'];
                        $hello = explode("@", $str);
                        $_SESSION ['emails'] = $hello;
                        echo "<tr>";
                        foreach ($_SESSION ['emails'] as $value)
                        {
                            echo "<td>$value</td>";
                        }
                        echo "</tr>";
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $data = $_POST;
    if (isset($data['submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['all_post'][] =  $data;
    }
    header('Location:screen3_2.php'); exit();
?>
```

Comment: kindly add full code of your second page, to understand your question better.

Comment: That's all i have(controller) on my 2nd page.

Comment: you're already accessing `$_POST` data in your controller code second line, and setting into session variable in fourth line, kindly be clear on your question.

Comment: yes, so what do i need to change?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see,
In your code you are posting your form data to controller, not the second page.
Though you are storing your data to `$_SESSION` in your controller page, That's how you're able to access data from second page.

**Solution** :
either access data on second page using `$_SESSION`, or
POST your first page to directly second page, and access data using `$_POST`.

Comment: My controller is on 2nd page.

Answer (score 0):

When the following code executes, it does **NOT** send the POST vars with it.
They are lost at that point.  However, you have stored the data in the session.

```
header('Location:screen3_2.php'); exit();
```

Also note that the following code:

```
$str = $_POST['email_text'];
$hello = explode("@", $str);
$_SESSION ['emails'] = $hello;
```

Will store the two parts of exactly one email. You mentioned that you want to store multiple emails and this code will not accomplish that.

It seems to me that what you want to do is to keep going back to the same page and reusing the form while collecting email addresses.  Please confirm.

Try this:

Do not use a separate controller file. Take that code and remove the redirect. Put that code at the top of the file. This way you collect 
all the email addresses from $_POST.

```
<?php
    // Taken from 'controller'
    session_start();
    // Only process post if it exists
    if ( ! empty($_POST) ) {
        $data = $_POST;
        if ( isset($data['submit']) ) {
            $_SESSION['all_post'][] =  $data;
        }
    }
    // No redirect
 ?>
<?php // put the form here ?>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" >
<input type="email" class="form-control"  name="email_text" id="email_text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    // output all the email addresses collected
    if(isset($_SESSION['all_post']) && !empty($_SESSION['all_post'])) {
        foreach($_SESSION['all_post'] as $key=>$value) {
            $parts = explode('@', $value['email_text']);
                    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $parts[0] ?></td> <?php // before @ ?>
            <td><?= $parts[1] ?></td> <?php // after @ ?>
        </tr>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes need to use the same form which on submit keeps the previous values also

Comment: as you said, you need more email addresses, then I would suggest to do it using AJAX.

Comment: It could be implemented without AJAX by cycling through the same page/code every time, storing the entered values as it goes.  A solution like this would have to store the values somewhere since each iteration can only collect one email address. The session is fine if this is just some code to learn. A real application would need something better like Redis or a database.

Comment: I can only use PHP

Comment: please use my code as a reference i didn't understand what and where to replace some parts

Comment: I added some comments to the code.  I removed almost all your html for clarity purposes.

Comment: It works for single page but what i will do if i want to take email value from a new page,Suppose i created a form and want to take its email value and split the email in two parts in a new page.

Comment: If you want to use multiple PHP files, it will be more difficult. You will need a way to store the data and send it to the other page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151857/discussion-between-naveen-dharni-and-ryantxr).